# fstab mount options for umask, fmask, dmask for ntfs with noexec

Tags: fstab, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I have a ntfs partition and when I mount it with default options in fstab I get for files and directories:
rwxrwxrwx = 0777
Obviously ntfs does not support "noexec" option and I do not want 'x' flag to the files and directories. So I'd like to ask what values shall I set to fmask, dmask and umask?
When I set umask=0666

```
/dev/sda3       /ntfsPartition  ntfs-3g     defaults,noatime,umask=0666,locale=en_US.utf8,errors=ro 0 0
```

I get d--x--x--x for the mount directory of the partition. I can go the directory:

```
cd /ntfsPartition
```

but I cannot read the content:

```
ls /ntfsPartition
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21):

The `x` flag is necessary for directories, in order to access their contents.

With just the `r` flag on a directory, you can get a directory listing, but cannot access the files and subdirectories within it. With just the `x` flag on a directory, you won't see the directory listing, but may be able to access files and sub-directories if their permissions allow it *and you can specify the exact name of the thing you're trying to access.* So, in most cases, you have only two generally useful permissions choices for directories: `r-x` and `rwx`.

So, since the `umask` mount option applies to both files and directories, and you don't want the `x` flag on files, you'll need to use `fmask` and `dmask` only, so you can place one set of permissions on files and another on directories.

The permissions and the corresponding mask numbers:

- `rwx` = mask number 0
- `rw-` = mask number 1 (not very useful for directories)
- `r-x` = mask number 2
- `r--` = mask number 3
- `-wx` = mask number 4 (special case: an approximation of a "write-only directory")
- `-w-` = mask number 5 (not very useful for directories)
- `--x` = mask number 6 (for directories: access by known filenames only)
- `---` = mask number 7 (no access)

If you want full access to directories, and everything except the `x` flag for files, you'll need 0 for the corresponding `dmask` number and `1` for the `fmask` number.

For NTFS-3g mask numbers, the first digit will be always 0, to denote that the values are in octal numbers. The second digit will specify access for the user specified with the `uid=` option (or for the user doing the mounting, if not specified), the third digit will specify access for the group identified with the `gid=` option, and the last digit will specify access for everyone else.

If this is your personal system and there are no other users who would need access to the NTFS filesystem, you could use the `id` command to identify your UID number, and then use mount options `uid=<your UID here>,dmask=0077,fmask=0177`. This would result all the files on the NTFS filesystem appearing as owned by you and with permissions `-rw-------`, and directories with `drwx------`.

If there are other users who would need access to the NTFS filesystem, you could create a group for the NTFS access, add all the appropriate users to that group, then also specify the GID of that group in mount options: `uid=<your UID here>,gid=<NTFS access group GID here>,dmask=0007,fmask=0117`. This would give anyone in the group the same access as you have: files `-rw-rw----` and directories `drwxrwx---`.

Or you could keep the write access for yourself but give the group members read-only access: `uid=<your UID here>,gid=<NTFS access group GID here>,dmask=0027,fmask=0137`. This would result in permissions `-rw-r-----` for files and `drwxr-x---` for directories.

Or if you want to grant full access to multiple user accounts and read-only access to everyone else, then the mount options would be: `uid=<your UID here>,gid=<NTFS access group GID here>,dmask=0002,fmask=0113`. That would result in permissions `-rw-rw-r--` for files and `drwxrwxr-x` for directories.

---

Instead of using mount options to specify permissions to NTFS files and directories, it is also possible to create a *user mapping file* to map Windows NTFS security IDs (SIDs) to Unix-style UIDs and GIDs. There's even a `ntfsusermap` tool that will help in creating that file for you. Once you have created the mapping file, you'll only have to place it into `<root of NTFS filesystem>/.NTFS-3G/UserMapping` and it will be automatically used the next time you mount the filesystem. After that, the real NTFS file ownerships and permissions will be used in Linux as applicable, and they can be persistently manipulated with `chown`/`chgrp`/`chmod` too.

See `man ntfs-3g` and `man ntfsusermap` for details.

If you're dual-booting Linux and Windows, you might want to get [a Windows command line version of `ntfsusermap`](https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/ntfsusermap.html) and generate the user mapping file while running Windows instead. It might be easier, as with the Windows version of the tool you can see the actual Windows usernames rather than just filenames and their associated SIDs.

Even if you don't want the Windows version of `ntfsusermap`, the page contains a more verbose description of how to use the tool, which may be helpful on Linux side of things too.