# can't uncheck "allow executing file as a program" from txt files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, executable

I can't remember how i have made all .txt files on my external hard-drive with NTFS executable in Ubuntu, so that whenever i double-click any .txt file on that disk or open the right-click menu, it only appears to run the file instead of trying to open it with text editor applications.

I can see an option **"allow executing file as a program"** in the file properties is checked, but i can't uncheck it by click (it automatically gets checked again).

I have tried the following command but it doesn't work:

```bsh
chmod -x *.txt
```

How can i revert my txt files configuration back to normal behaviour?

Comment: You need to be the owner to alter permissions. A file called "something.txt" can be a genuine script file which is meant to be executable, although a very badly badly named one. You could try sudo chmod -x *.txt which will make every .txt file in your current directory non-executable.

Comment: @JeremyBoden i'm the owner. adding sudo didn't change anything. i see this problem in all my text files, not just txt files having codes or scripts.

Comment: "when I double click..." - so you are running a desktop environment. Whilst it is probably gnome, you need to tell us which one it is.

Comment: Do you have a "properties" menu item on the right-click menu?

Comment: What filesystem are these files on?

Comment: Are the text files in a directory mounted from a windows file share or a partition (or disk or usb thumb drive etc) formatted as FAT or NTFS?

Comment: @icarus yeah it's gnome in ubuntu 20

Comment: @cas now that i see, only the txt files in my NTFS external HDD have this problem. the files on my system are doing ok.

Comment: OK, you need to change the permission that are set when the NTFS drive is mounted.  Find the line that mounts it in `/etc/fstab`.  You'll want to add or change the `fmask` value so that regular files aren't executable.   There's a good answer about this at [fstab mount options for umask, fmask, dmask for ntfs with noexec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521072/7696)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fstab mount options for umask, fmask, dmask for ntfs with noexec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396904/fstab-mount-options-for-umask-fmask-dmask-for-ntfs-with-noexec)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chmod is not working on ntfs-3g partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604674/chmod-is-not-working-on-ntfs-3g-partition)

Comment: @cas i don't know much about Linux configuration. the links have actually confused me with their complexity. i don't quite understand what command to run in my terminal to solve this problem.