# cryptsetup with veracrypt container: set encoding?

Tags: character-encoding, cryptsetup, veracrypt

I'm trying to unlock (and later mount) a veracrypt container like this:

```
sudo cryptsetup --type tcrypt --veracrypt open /home/me/my_container.vc my_container
sudo mount /dev/mapper/my_container /media/my_container
```

But when I look at the files in the container, some of them have incorrect encoding due to non-English characters being used. In VeraCrypt, I used to set `iocharset=utf8` in *Preferences* > *Mount* options to solve this problem. How do I do this in `cryptsetup`?

Mind you: we're talking about the encoding inside the container, *not* about the encoding for the keyboard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iocharset` is a mount option, not something VeraCrypt specific, just add it to your `mount` command:

```
sudo mount -o iocharset=utf8 /dev/mapper/my_container /media/my_container
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks for your reply, that solve _that_ part of the problem. One issue remains: if I mount the device like that, I only have read access, but no write. The problem seems to lie with the ownership: all files are mounted with root as the owner. chmod -c -R my_username won't work / is rejected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume the filesystem is NTFS or VFAT, you can use `uid`/`gid` or `fmask` options, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396904/fstab-mount-options-for-umask-fmask-dmask-for-ntfs-with-noexec) for details. You also do the mount with `udisksctl mount -b /dev/mapper/my_container -o iocharset=utf8`, `udisksctl` should take care of using the correct `uid` and `gid` values when called as non-root user.

Comment: Great, thanks for the hint mate! (I notice I've still got a _lot_ to learn here.) You're correct, the filesystem is a FAT type. Using `udisksctl` does give me write permissions. However it doesn't seem to allow me to mount my container to a specific location: it just mounts it to /media/<username>/<someGenericName>. I'd like to mount it to /media/<specificFolder>. Is there a way to pass that as a parameter as well? I must admit I'm a bit overwhelmed by the man pages of both `mount` and `udisksctl`.